# mysql slave stops after restart mysql in master master setup

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

We upgraded from mysql 5.5 tot mysql 5.7 master-master cluster .

Now ervery time i restart mysql on one of the two host the mysql slave stops.

What is changed in mysql 5.7, how can fix this so i can do maintance with have to fix this every thim :

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 172.31.1.214
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000059
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 64291814
               Relay_Log_File: DB01-relay-bin.000137
                Relay_Log_Pos: 3952
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000059
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 1032
                   Last_Error: Could not execute Update_rows event on table somedb.vb_session; Can't find record in 'vb_session', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.000059, end_log_pos 64084340
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 64083618
              Relay_Log_Space: 212903
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1032
               Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Update_rows event on table somedb.vb_session; Can't find record in 'vb_session', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.000059, end_log_pos 64084340
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 2
                  Master_UUID: 38155e16-cb5b-11e6-bc6c-005056b28a86
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State:
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 170105 15:59:21
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ^DBye
```

Comment: did you upgrade on both ends of the master-master cluster? it looks to me like the data is inconsistent already, you may want to run pt-table-checksum

Comment: i did a fresh install

Comment: When i run your command i get :
root@Backup2Bit:~# pt-table-checksum -h db01 -u bas -pmysecretpwd
Replica DB02 has binlog_format ROW which could cause pt-table-checksum to break replication.  Please read "Replicas using row-based replication" in the LIMITATIONS section of the tool's documentation.  If you understand the risks, specify --no-check-binlog-format to disable this check.

Comment: `--no-check-binlog-format` use it as suggested by the tool :)